# Why does Bash allocate extra array spots if I have dashes in entries?

Tags: arrays, bash

I tell Bash (v4.4) to give me an array, and I ask how long it is:

```sh
$ list=(one two three four)
$ echo ${#list}
3
```

Why are there so many more entries if I have `-` in some words?

```sh
$ list=(one-two three-four)
$ echo ${#list}
7
```

If I ask for the items, most of them are empty. All the ones with values are first, despite the (apparently) odd behavior with `-` in words.

```sh
$ for ix in $(seq 0 ${#list}); do
>     echo "- ${list[$ix]}"
> done
- one-two
- three-four
- 
- 
- 
- 
-
```

What is going on?

Comment: `echo "${#list[@]}"` if you want to count array elements instead of the length of element 0. Or `declare -p list` to _see_ your array's contents and answer any question about how many elements there are.

Comment: Putting it a little differently: `$list` is identical to `${list[0]}`; you need to use `${list[@]}` to refer to something _as an array_. Thus, `${#list}` is the length of `${list[0]}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"One-two" has seven characters. You find the length of the `list` array with echo `${#list[@]}`.

`echo ${#list}` gives you the string length of the first list element. For Bash, i recommend the following cheatsheet: https://devhints.io/bash

Comment: OP, notice that even the first length check was wrong. It printed `3` for an array with `4` elements.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks. I just thought it was 0-indexed and printing the IX of the last item. Bad luck choosing "one" for the first element.